# Does iPhone allow Light sensors as input?

Tags: iphone, sensors, light

I was just wondering whether iPhone developement allows light sensors to be used, as buttons or action elements??

I found this link online...

Possible to use Light Sensor as a Button? [Archive] - Touch Arcade

If anyone could shed some light on the issue, I'd appreciate the help?

Answer (score 3):

An official answer by an Apple rep is on the [Apple Dev Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/274229) (login required):

> There's no supported way to get at the
>   ambient light sensor.  If you'd like
>   to see such support added in the
>   future, I encourage you to file a bug
>   describing your requirements.  While
>   we may have seen similar requests many
>   times before, a fresh bug report will
>   allow you to express your needs in
>   your own terms, and allow iOS
>   engineering to gauge the level of
>   demand. http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter

Answer (score -1):

In the 3.0 SDK the UIDevice class has the `proximityState` and `proximityMonitoringEnabled` properties.

```
BOOL buttonPressed = [UIDevice currentDevice].proximityState;
```

... gives you the current state.

Keep in mind that the iPod Touch does not have a proximity sensor.

Comment: The proximity sensor isn't the light sensor

Comment: The ambient light sensor is NOT the same as the proximity sensor (says the person who's only feedback option is a comment as I'm not hip enough to down-vote a candidate answer)