# detecting if iPhone is in a dark room

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there a way to use the iPhone proximity sensor to detect whether the phone is in a room with no light?

This question seems to imply that this is not possible...[Does iPhone allow Light sensors as input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301435/does-iphone-allow-light-sensors-as-input?lq=1)

Comment: There should already be an ambient light sensor in the iPhone I believe

Comment: @user2277872 There's an important warning at the top of the IO doc you provided I/O Kit is a low-level framework communicating with hardware or kernel services. Although it is a public framework, Apple discourages developers from using it, and any apps using it will be rejected from App Store.

Answer (score 30):

Here's a much simpler way of using the camera to find out how bright a scene is. (Obviously, it only reads the data that can be "seen" in the camera's field of view, so it's not a true ambient light sensor...)

Using the AVFoundation framework, set up a video input and then, using the ImageIO framework, read the metadata that's coming in with each frame of the video feed (you can ignore the actual video data):

```
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
      didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
             fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
  CFDictionaryRef metadataDict = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(NULL, 
    sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
  NSDictionary *metadata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] 
    initWithDictionary:(__bridge NSDictionary*)metadataDict];
  CFRelease(metadataDict);
  NSDictionary *exifMetadata = [[metadata 
    objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary] mutableCopy];
  float brightnessValue = [[exifMetadata 
    objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifBrightnessValue] floatValue];
}
```

You now have the Brightness Value for the scene updated (typically—you can configure this) 15-30 times per second. Lower numbers are darker.

Comment: Do you know the possible range of the brightness level? I didn't find it on the internet...

Comment: Eyeballing the data, it looks like it's probably -10 to +15. The range I can actually *get* is about -8.5 to +13.5.

Comment: I actually get data between +14 and -7... So there is no documentation on this?

Comment: I just an other idea. This is EXIF data, so this is no iOS specific value. These values are called the `APEX-System`. I read the Wiki article but didn't find absolute values like "from ... to ..." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APEX_system

Comment: Just want to thank you and confirm that it works also on iOS8

Comment: your guys are the best!!! could somebody provide some sample code to this? eg how to set up the video feed?

Comment: could you please convert your answer as Swift 3? Will be very useful

Comment: Crash may happen by chance.      Thread 35 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183cf97f8 _CFBasicHashCreateCopy :592 (in CoreFoundation)
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183d1b328 _CFDictionaryCreateCopy :156 (in CoreFoundation)

Comment: I doubt that the crash related to this code, which I've been using (for different purposes) for five years on commercial products.

Comment: There are tens of millions users using my commercial products  every day. It happens more than twenty times a day, on average。 This crash never happens before.

Comment: CFDictionaryCreateCopy is in CFDictionary.c . I wonder some bad memory problem, but I'm unable to get more infomation.

Comment: I can only claim hundreds of thousands of users, but they're all running (exactly) this code >15 times per second, and it doesn't lead to crashes. Without seeing your code, I can't really comment further...

Answer (score 9):

Swift 4.2 version based upon [Wildaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228723/wildaker)'s code.  Xcode 10 refused to allow it to be a Float, but the double has worked.

```
func getBrightness(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> Double {
    let rawMetadata = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(allocator: nil, target: sampleBuffer, attachmentMode: CMAttachmentMode(kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate))
    let metadata = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(nil, 0, rawMetadata) as NSMutableDictionary
    let exifData = metadata.value(forKey: "{Exif}") as? NSMutableDictionary
    let brightnessValue : Double = exifData?[kCGImagePropertyExifBrightnessValue as String] as! Double
    return brightnessValue
}
```

Comment: Work for me! Perfect!

Comment: And remember to import AVFoundation.

Answer (score 8):

Proximity sensor is not what you should be looking for. Ambient light sensor it is. Apparently that API is undocumented or not available at all for developers. An alternative way of detecting if iPhone is in a dark room would be using the camera and obtaining the luminosity . Here's a good guide on how to do that,

https://www.transpire.com/insights/blog/obtaining-luminosity-ios-camera/

Comment: It's really a shame you don't get official access to this sensor.

Answer (score 1):

There is much simpler solution for this if anyone needs. Use screen brightness to detect the light conditions:

**0** - 0.3 (Dark)

0.4 - **1** (Bright)

Tweak as needed:

```
switch UIScreen.main.brightness {
    case 0 ... 0.3:
        print("LOW LIGHT")
    default:
        print("ENOUGH LIGHT")
    }
```

Comment: The brightness of the screen won't be consistent unless automatic brightness level is enabled. This is clever but very fragile way of accomplishing the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to access the ambient light sensor data through IOKit framework, Apple discourages developers from using it, and any apps using it will be rejected from App Store.

But it is possible to deduce the luminosity of the environment approximately through the camera. That is by implementing the camera through AVFoundation framework and processing the meta data coming though each of the camera frames. Refer to this answer on question : [How to get light value from AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46842115/5824486)

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing some Augmented Reality stuff using ARKit you can get the `lightEstimate` value on each frame of the video feed from the `ARSession`.

See [documentation on this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2878306-lightestimate).