# Showing "Low light" as message when there is low light while using iphone camera

Tags: ios7, brightness, ambient, light-sensor

I have a requirement where I need to show a message "Low light" when there is a low light around the iphone front camera. I was searching for public API which does this but didn't find anything. Also did check ambient light sensor but nothing helped.

Can some tell me is there a way to identify the low light state while using the iphone front camera?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AVFoundation, and then you can monitor the Brightness Value that's in the video stream's metadata, as explained in [my answer to another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22836060/1228723). If you're not viewing the video feed, you may want to ramp it down to 6 fps, as that will give you a lower floor for the low light (and thus more control).