# Updating published variables using DispatchQueue.main.async in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, dispatch-queue, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I am working on a SwiftUI app that displays an `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and also implements the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` protocol to perform some custom logic in `captureOutput(_: didOutput: from:)`.  The custom logic was working as expected and updating my view as expected until I implemented the video preview layer.

Now, only the video preview layer is updated within the view. Both the video preview layer and the update to the published variable occur within a call to `DispatchQueue.main.async`. Is this appropriate?

I also have a suspicion that I may need to implement some logic within the `updateUIViewController(_: context:)` function within the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` struct I am using to display the video peview layer in my view. The docs provided for this function are not very helpful, can anyone provide any tips on how it should be used?

```
class VideoStream: UIViewController, ObservableObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    @Published var luminosityReading : Double = 0.0

        ...
        // AVCaptureSession configuration entered, input added, establish preview layer:
        // Currently working on DispatchQueue(label: "VideoStreamSetupQueue")
        layer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        ...
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.layer)
        }

        // Establish output for luminosity calculation
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        guard
            session.canAddOutput(videoOutput)
        else {
            print("Error creating video output")
            return
        }
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "VideoStreamForCaptureOutputQueue"))
        session.addOutput(videoOutput)
        
        session.sessionPreset = .medium
        session.commitConfiguration()
        session.startRunning()
        ...

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        // custom logic to calculate luminosity
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(luminosity)  // value changes as expected
            self.luminosityReading = luminosity  // view not updated with printed value
        }
    }
```

Establishing a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` to display video preview layer in a SwiftUI view:

```
struct HostedVideoPreviewLayer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        return VideoStream()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        // video preview layer works as expected
        // text unrelated to this struct (see below) is not updating
    }
}
```

Creating the view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var videoStream = VideoStream()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HostedVideoPreviewLayer()
            Text(String(format: "%.2f   Lux", videoStream.luminosityReading))
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

**Minimal Reproducible Example:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var videoStream = VideoStream()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HostedVideoPreviewLayer()
            Text(String(format: "%.2f   Lux", videoStream.luminosityReading))
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

class VideoStream: UIViewController, ObservableObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    
    @Published var luminosityReading : Double = 0.0
    
    private let session = AVCaptureSession()
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "VideoStreamSetupQueue")
    private var layer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
    var screenRect: CGRect!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        authorizeCapture()
        queue.async {
            self.authorizeCapture()
        }
    }

    func authorizeCapture() {
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
        case .authorized: // The user has previously granted access to the camera.
            beginCapture()
        case .notDetermined: // The user has not yet been asked for camera access.
            queue.suspend()
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { granted in
                if granted {
                    self.beginCapture()
                    self.queue.resume()
                }
            }
            
        default:
            return
        }
    }

    func beginCapture() {
        session.beginConfiguration()
        let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
        
        // Add device as input
        guard
            let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice!),
            session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput)
        else {
            print("Camera selection failed")
            return
        }
        session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
        
        // Establish preview layer
        screenRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        layer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenRect.size.width, height: 300)
        layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        layer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.layer)
        }
        
        // Establish output for luminosity calculation
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        guard
            session.canAddOutput(videoOutput)
        else {
            print("Error creating video output")
            return
        }
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "VideoStreamForCaptureOutputQueue"))
        session.addOutput(videoOutput)
        
        session.sessionPreset = .medium
        session.commitConfiguration()
        session.startRunning()
    }

    // From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921326/how-to-get-light-value-from-avfoundation/46842115#46842115
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        // Retrieving EXIF data of camara frame buffer
                
        let rawMetadata = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(allocator: nil, target: sampleBuffer, attachmentMode: CMAttachmentMode(kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate))
        let metadata = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(nil, 0, rawMetadata) as NSMutableDictionary
        let exifData = metadata.value(forKey: "{Exif}") as? NSMutableDictionary
        
        let FNumber : Double = exifData?["FNumber"] as! Double
        let ExposureTime : Double = exifData?["ExposureTime"] as! Double
        let ISOSpeedRatingsArray = exifData!["ISOSpeedRatings"] as? NSArray
        let ISOSpeedRatings : Double = ISOSpeedRatingsArray![0] as! Double
        let CalibrationConstant : Double = 50
        
        //Calculating the luminosity
        let luminosity : Double = (CalibrationConstant * FNumber * FNumber ) / ( ExposureTime * ISOSpeedRatings )
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(luminosity)  // value changes as expected
            self.luminosityReading = luminosity  // view not updated with recent value
        }
    }

    override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        screenRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenRect.size.width, height: screenRect.size.height)
        
        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
            // Home button on top
            case UIDeviceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown:
                layer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
                     
            // Home button on right
            case UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft:
                layer.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
                    
            // Home button on left
            case UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight:
                layer.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeLeft
                     
            // Home button at bottom
            case UIDeviceOrientation.portrait:
                layer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
                        
            default:
                break
        }

    }
}

struct HostedVideoPreviewLayer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        return VideoStream()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        // video preview layer works as expected
        // text unrelated to this struct is not updating
    }
}

[1]: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable/updateuiviewcontroller(_:context:)
```

Comment: The first big issue to address is that you are creating multiple instances of VideoStream (one in your Content view and one in the Hosted view) that do not share a luminosity variable, since again, they are different instances. I suggest you senate the model from the views — store the luminosity in a single place, owned by the parent view, that can then be passed down to the child views.

Comment: An Observable Object shouldn’t be a UIViewController it just isn’t good practice. All you need is the session to populate a uiview with the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working solution instead passes the `AVCaptureSession` created in `VideoStream` as a parameter to a custom view `VideoPreviewHolder`. I use a state object to ensure the session is available (if not, a progress indicator is displayed) and then display the preview layer. I hope this may be useful to others:

class VideoPreview: UIView {
private var session: AVCaptureSession!

```
init(runningSession session: AVCaptureSession) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    self.session = session
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
}

var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
    return layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
}

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    
    if self.superview != nil {
        self.videoPreviewLayer.session = self.session
        self.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
    }
}
```

}

struct VideoPreviewHolder: UIViewRepresentable {
public var runningSession: AVCaptureSession

```
typealias UIViewType = VideoPreview

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> VideoPreview {
    VideoPreview(runningSession: runningSession)
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: VideoPreview, context: Context) {
    
}
```

}

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var videoStream = VideoStream() // this class definition is in original question body
    
    var body: some View {
        if (!videoStream.cameraAccess) {
            // request access
        } else {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    if (videoStream.session != nil) {
                        VideoPreviewHolder(runningSession: videoStream.session)
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, idealHeight: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    } else {
                        ProgressView()
                    }
            ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```